Why my interstitial ads unit id is highlighted in purple in the admob dashboard and how can I fix it
My app shows the interstitial ads unit name highlighted in purple and it's not displaying ads in my app but it is working in unity .
I tried everything but nothing is happening but the ads are showing ad request and also loading ads in unity editor what should I do to fix this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
